# Get index of element in list in list

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have a two dimensional list and for every list in the list I want to print its index and for every element in each list I also want to print its index. Here is what I tried:

```
l = [[0,0,0],[0,1,1],[1,0,0]]

def Printme(arg1, arg2):
    print arg1, arg2

for i in l:
    for j in i:
        Printme(l.index(i), l.index(j))
```

But the output is:

```
0 0  # I was expecting: 0 0
0 0  #                  0 1
0 0  #                  0 2
1 0  #                  1 0
1 1  #                  1 1
1 1  #                  1 2
2 0  #                  2 0
2 1  #                  2 1
2 1  #                  2 2
```

Why is that? How can I make it do what I want?

Comment: It won't work that way because `list.index` short circuits upon finding the first value equal to your search value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Help on `list.index`:

> L.index(value, [start, [stop]]) -> integer -- return **first** index of
>   value. Raises ValueError if the value is not present.

You should use `enumerate()` here:

```
>>> l = [[0,0,0],[0,1,1],[1,0,0]]
for i, x in enumerate(l):
    for j, y in enumerate(x):
        print i,j,'-->',y
...         
0 0 --> 0
0 1 --> 0
0 2 --> 0
1 0 --> 0
1 1 --> 1
1 2 --> 1
2 0 --> 1
2 1 --> 0
2 2 --> 0
```

help on `enumerate`:

```
>>> print enumerate.__doc__
enumerate(iterable[, start]) -> iterator for index, value of iterable

Return an enumerate object.  iterable must be another object that supports
iteration.  The enumerate object yields pairs containing a count (from
start, which defaults to zero) and a value yielded by the iterable argument.
enumerate is useful for obtaining an indexed list:
    (0, seq[0]), (1, seq[1]), (2, seq[2]), ...
```

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary why not just do `help(enumerate)` it's much simpler for beginners

Comment: @jamylak well the only reason is output of `enumerate.__doc__` is easier to copy than the output of `help(enumerate)` which starts `Vi`.
Though on IPython I usually prefer `enumerate?`.

Answer (score 0):

`.index(i)` gives you the index of the *first* occurrence of `i`. Therefore, you always find the same indices.